# Xcode 11.2.1 through an error (Cannot find protocol declaration for) on app-Swift.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, migration, xcode11.2.1

I recently migrating Xcode 10.3 - 11.2.1, the project combination of **Objective-C and Swift**, I fixed most of the issue and finally I stuck in app-Swift.h file. It shows error "**Cannot find protocol declaration for**". Its working good in Xcode 10.2 not in Xcode 11.2.1

Kindly provide me an suggestion to fix this issue.

[image]

Swift Code Below

```
extension FaceScanHelper: AcuantHGLiveFaceCaptureDelegate {
    
    func liveFaceDetailsCaptured(liveFaceDetails: LiveFaceDetails?) {
        
        if(liveFaceDetails?.faceRect != nil && liveFaceDetails?.image != nil){
            
            faceImage = liveFaceDetails?.image
            
            let translatedFaceRect = self.calculateFaceRect(faceBounds: (liveFaceDetails?.faceRect?.toCGRect())!, clearAperture:(liveFaceDetails?.cleanAperture?.toCGRect())!)
            
            
            var width = (translatedFaceRect.width)
            width = 1.1*width
            
            var height = (translatedFaceRect.height)
            height = 1.3*height
            
            let x = (translatedFaceRect.origin.x) + ((translatedFaceRect.width)-width)
            let y = (translatedFaceRect.origin.y) + ((translatedFaceRect.height)-height)
            let faceRect =  CGRect.init(x: x, y: y, width: width, height:height)
            self.faceOval?.removeFromSuperlayer()
            faceOval = CAShapeLayer()
            faceOval?.path = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: faceRect).cgPath
            faceOval?.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            faceOval?.strokeColor = UIColor.init(rgb: APP_THEME_COLOR).cgColor //UIColor.red.cgColor
            faceOval?.lineWidth = 5.0
            
            self.videoPreviewLayer.addSublayer((faceOval)!)
            if(liveFaceDetails?.isLiveFace)!{
                
                if let face = liveFaceDetails?.image{
                    if(!isReported){
                        isReported = true
                        self.delegate?.liveFaceCaptured!(face, error: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if(liveFaceDetails == nil || liveFaceDetails?.faceRect == nil){
            self.faceOval?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
}
```

See the Swift file method declaration on below the screenshot
[image]

See the errors list its below screenshot all in same app-Swift.h
[image]
[image]

Comment: How and where is that protocol declared?

Comment: @DávidPásztor it's inside the third party library

Comment: and its working well in Xcode 10.3

Comment: import header from that third party library, then import app-Swift.h

Comment: @Cy-4AH its imported in swift file. app-Swift.h is autogeneration file for communicate swift and objectiveC

Also without any changes its working well in Xcode 10.3 (For your information)

Comment: Another alternative is to add `@_exported ` before  third party library import, if you don't want import it every where before `app-Swift.h`

Comment: I added @_exported before library import on my scanhelper.swift its an concept implementation file and I'm not able to modify anything on app-Swift.h because its an autogenerate

Comment: You don't need modify app-Swift.h, modify file where you import it.

Comment: @Cy-4AH yes I tried 

@_exported import AcuantHGLiveness
@_exported import AcuantImagePreparation
@_exported import AcuantCommon
@_exported import AcuantCamera

Not working

Comment: It doesn't looks like import in objc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216615/discussion-between-anand3777-and-cy-4ah).